# How to include stylesheet file only for one div?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

i have to include a css file for only one div and to include another css file for second div. How can we do this?
i have tried Switch cases for this, but when it loads css for one case it is still showing the css effect in other case also.

here is what i have tried so far:

```
<?php
    switch ($type_show1):   
    case 'welcome1':
    //default:
?>
<link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />    // css to include
                <div class="page-header">
                    <div class="page-title">
                        <h5>Booking Management</h5>
                        <span>Good morning, Admin!</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- /page header -->

<?php
break;
endswitch;  
    ?>

<?php
    switch ($type_show2):
    case 'welcome2':
    //default:
?>
                <!--<link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />-->                   // css not to include
                <div class="page-header">
                    <div class="page-title">
                        <h5>Booking Management</h5>
                        <span>Good morning, Admin!</span>
                    </div>
                </div>

<?php
break;
endswitch;  
?>
```

Any Help :)

Comment: you put your style inside the div , there is no way to make the page read the style sheet for only one div

Comment: you can also use javascript to add a class with the style you want to that div

Comment: no i have to include external css file here,,, but different for both of the cases, is it possible?

Comment: no this is impossible

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whenever you add a css file to the page, it applies to the whole document. However looking at your code, what I think you're trying to do is display 1 chunk of html under one condition and another chunk under a separate condition. To do this change your code to this:

```
<?php
    switch ($type_show1):   
    case 'welcome1':
    //default:
?>
         <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> 

<?php
    break;
    case 'welcome2'  :
?>
         <link href="css/main2.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>    

<?php
    break;
?>

                <div class="page-header">
                    <div class="page-title">
                        <h5>Booking Management</h5>
                        <span>Good morning, Admin!</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- /page header -->
```

Speaking to what you actually said about using one stylesheet per element. **It is possible** using Web Components, http://webcomponents.org/, and shadow DOM, http://webcomponents.org/articles/introduction-to-shadow-dom/, but I think in your situation it would be best to simply give each `div` an id or a class and apply the css specifically to that id or class from one css stylesheet.

**UPDATE**

To apply CSS to two different divs do this:

HTML

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="page-header" id="div1">
            <div class="page-title">
                <h5>Booking Management</h5>
                <span>Good morning, Admin!</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="page-header" id="div2">
            <div class="page-title">
                <h5>Booking Management</h5>
                <span>Good morning, Admin!</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS (main.css)

```
#div1 {
    //Some CSS Styles to apply to the first div
}
#div2 {
    //Some CSS Styles to apply to the second div
}
```

Comment: hiii... thanks so much for your help, but i have to show both of the divs at the same time, then is it possible to show different css effect on both of the divs at the same time, by the solution provided by you. Because i have tried the same thing but it doesn't help.

Comment: See my update. That will allow you to apply CSS to two different divs using the `#div1` and `#div2` selectors.

Answer (score -1):

Nope, you can't use a StyleSheet for just one div

create a new div and use your special CSS for that div.